# getting `local': argument out of range (ArgumentError) while working with mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I am trying to get 'Auto_increment' using mysql2 adapter with ruby 192. my code is

```
require 'mysql2' 
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( :adapter => 'mysql2', :database => 'my_db', :username => 'root', :password => '' )
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users'"
```

whenever I am trying to print the fields and data using a loop, it gives me this error -

***`local': argument out of range (ArgumentError)***

But if I change my query to

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "select * from users"
```

it works perfectly,
any Idea ?